# Jquery auto complete validate data

Tags: jquery, spring, autocomplete

I have implemented auto complete drop down using spring mvc. Now my question is when any user select/choose any value from auto complete drop down, then How can i sure that the selected value is correct or not? in other words i want to ensure that whether user selected the correct value from auto complete or not. Because user can type random string in input text box and submit it(Technically, i also make sure when user select any value from drop down, then submit will be visible to the user, and if user type incorrect data, the button shouldn't be activate).

Here is a code

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "input[name='creditCheck']" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source:function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "creditCheck.ajax",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        maxRows: 6,
                        startsWith: request.term
                    },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.creditCheckData, function( item) {
                        return {
                            creditName: item.creditName,
                        }
                    }));
                }

                });
            },
```

The above code words fine, it get the list from server and displays the auto complete data.In following code i am just toggling the button.But i also make sure when user select any value from drop down, then submit will be visible to the user, and if user type incorrect data, the button shouldn't be activate.

```
$('input[name="creditCheck"]').bind("change keyup", function () {
    if ($(this).val()!="") {
        $(this).nextAll("button[name='add']:first").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).nextAll("button[name='add']:first").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: You're assuming that your autocomplete service is returning bad data?

Comment: cache your results into an array and validate that the value is in array before submit. Likely best to do same at server

Comment: Justice, No my automate service returning right data but i want to validate that data with user input and based on data, i want to enable or disable "submit" button. Let say Service Returns{One,Two,Three, Four) data from controller and user type "Five" in input text field(definitely "Five" doesn't exist in list so its incorrect data). So at this point, i want to check whether "Five" does exist in array or not? If "Five" string does exist in array then i'll active the submit button otherwise submit button will be deactivate.

Comment: charlietfl, can u guide me bit more? how can i cache my result in array ?